# Constant version of a concept as return type in requires clause

Tags: c++, wrapper, c++20, c++-concepts

I have some class `A` that has some `const` and some non-`const` function, together with a fitting concept, say

```
class A {
public:
    void modify() {/* ... */}
    void print() const {/* ... */}
}

template<typename T>
concept LikeA = requires (T t, const T const_t) {
    { t.modify() } -> std::same_as<void>;
    { const_t.print() } -> std::same_as<void>;
}
static_assert(LikeA<A>);
```

A nice thing I noticed is that for some function taking `const LikeA auto &a` below code is actually legal:

```
void use (const LikeA auto &a) {
    a.print(); // fine, print is a const method
    // a.modify(); // illegal, a is a const reference [at least for use(A a) itself, but this is not my point here]
}

static_assert(!LikeA<const A>);

int main() {
    A a1;
    use(a1); //clear, as LikeA<A> holds
    const A a2;
    use(a2); //not obvious, as LikeA<const A> does not hold
}
```

I looked into the definitions on `cppreference`, and I could not really explain this behaviour, I expected it to be illegal, although intuitively, this really is what I want.

Now on to my real situation: I have a holder class `AHolder` that returns `const A&` as one of its methods, and I want a fitting concept for this holder class that also applies to any other holder holding anything that satisfies `LikeA`, so I tried:

```
class AHolder {
public:
    const A& getA() {return _a;}
private:
    const A _a;
};

template<typename T>
concept LikeAHolder = requires (T t) {
    {t.getA() } -> LikeA;
};

static_assert(LikeAHolder<AHolder>); //fails
```

This fails, since `const A&` simply doesn't satisfy `LikeA`, so i would love to adjust this to

```
template<typename T>
concept LikeAHolder = requires (T t) {
    {t.getA() } -> const LikeA; //invalid syntax
};

static_assert(LikeAHolder<AHolder>);
```

in similar spirit of the example with the `use` method also accepting `const A`.

Is there such a syntax to require the return type of `t.getA` to satisfy `LikeA` whilst considering that the return type will be `const`?

Additionally, how exactly are concepts checked in the `use(const LikeA auto &a)` method such that it behaves like explained?

(My first question is the more important one for me)

---

Some possible solutions that I have considered:

- Return a non-const-reference. This would make above code illegal, but of course would heavily ruin `const`-correctness, since `_a` would also have to be non-`const` and a user could just change the private attribute of `AHolder`. This is no option for me.
- Have two concepts `LikeA` and `LikeConstA`. The return type then could be `LikeConstA` only requiring the `const` methods. This should work, but feels really clumsy and really not how concepts should be used, also this introduces more concepts that necessary to an end-user, who has to bother with them, etc.
- In the concept `LikeA`, check whether the templated type `T` is constant (via `std::is_const`), and if so, don't require the non-`const`-methods. This works in above example, but has the undesired effect that we now simply have

```
class B {
public:
    void print() const {/* ... */}
}

static_assert(LikeA<const B>);
```

(for an already adapted `LikeA`, of course), which also just feels wrong.

- in the definition of `LikeA`, use `std::remove_reference` and `std::const_cast` to cast away references / constness, then check for the required functions. First, i don't know if this will always work for more complicated types, but even then, this now has the undesired effect that

```
static_assert(LikeA<const A>);
```

will be true, breaking (or at least bending) the semantics of the concept.

To summary and ensure you don't get me wrong, I would like to have a way that

- does enforce `const`-correctness
- does not use a second concept 'for the end-user'. With this I mean that it is of course okay to define auxiliary concepts or use some of the standard-library that help in defining above concept, but nothing that is actually required to use `A` and `LikeA` etc.
- does *not* simply ignore non-const requirements for const types (as I mentioned, this would be compiler-wise okay, but semantically feels wrong)
- does not define `LikeA<const A>` to be true

Ideally, there would just be a feature working like the already-mentioned

```
template<typename T>
concept LikeAHolder = requires (T t) {
    {t.getA() } -> const LikeA; //invalid syntax
};
```

Comment: One question per question, please. I'm not sure I even understand the motivation for the first question - why do you want syntax to check for a concept, that would be meaningless, since you're getting a `const` reference that you can't invoke the non-`const` members on anyway?

Comment: Yes, for this particular holder it will be useless to check for non-`const` members. But I have other methods returning and or / taking non-const versions of `A`, so there the checking really is relevant. I would like to have a way to tell a user that the reference he gets really is the same as the other classes satisfying `LikeA` he's seen before, except that he now gets it as const and thus cannot invoke non-const members.
I simply do not want to have 2 separate concepts for that and would like to have a way that naturally relates the two, being `LikeA` and being `LikeA` modulo being `const`

Comment: How about `const_cast`-ing away the const in your `LikeA` concept when you do `t.modify()`? Though that would make `LikeA<const A>` true.

Comment: If you are serious about const correctness, then why `const A& getA() {return _a;}` is not marked as a `const` function like that: `const A& getA() const {return _a;}`?

Comment: @Meowmere Yes, this was exactly part of my question

Comment: @Phil1970 because I just forgot to include this in these examples, you are right, although this was not the point of the question. In my code, this method is actually `const`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
{[](const LikeA auto&){}( t.getA() )}
```

Note that a non-`const&` returning `getA` will pass this.

I made a lambda that does a concept check, then ensured `t.getA()` passes it.

```
void use (const LikeA auto &a)
```

This is shorthand for

```
template<LikeA A>
void use (const A&a)
```

and when called with a `T const`, it deduces `A=T` not `A=T const`.  Why?  Because it is "more correct" abstractly. Concretely, there are a pile of rules for how template argument type deduction works.

Comment: As i just found out, the latest `clang` (12.0.1) does not support this. See [here](https://godbolt.org/z/bYTEjz7xiq) at the Compiler explorer. Is this supposed to be like this? Also, what does `clang (trunk)` refer to? Is this the latest development release?

Comment: @MaximilianKeßler Your link is non functional

Comment: @MaximilianKeßler Yes, trunk is current developmental version.  It appears the lambda support was added in https://reviews.llvm.org/D103380 that CL.  `void TakesLikeA(const LikeA auto&) {}` is the best workaround I can figure out.

Comment: but according to the standard this shall work, so this will be part of future `clang` ?

Comment: @MaximilianKeßler Yes, as described in the linked change, it was intentionally added to support standards compliance (but not to older versions of the standard).